# How can you log to GCP project when you have three different GCP Projects Referenced?

Tags: python, logging, google-bigquery, google-cloud-logging

Current setup:
GCP Project A holds the logs for application.
GCP Project B Namespace has the application running on Kubernetes.
GCP Project C holds the BigQuery Datasets and Tables that are queried by the Application.

We have a service account for Project B to query Project B.
We have a service account from Project B to log to Project A.

In the app, I am getting errors when I try to add logging client. I suspect its because the service account used to run the queries in the application is conflicting with the service account for logging.

Is there any way to get logging in place in this situation?

I tried adding GCP logging on my api route with logging client. I called a function to do the query with bigquery client.

Comment: Are these projects under a common organization?

Comment: Yes, they are under one organization.